# Opera mini css3 transform, gradient, transition polyfill?

Tags: javascript, css, polyfills, opera-mini

Are there any secretly maintained in some undergithub laboratories shims for that damn lil browser that doesn't support anything in favor of download speed optimization? Im interested in css3 transitions, gradients, transforms. Any sane ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About `transition`/`transform` in Opera Mini:**

Opera Mini use [`OBML`](http://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-binary-markup-language/). The OBML server farm renders the requested web page then takes a snapshot of it before converting it into OBML and sending it to the browser. So page in Opera Mini can't be animated by `css` or `javascript` or `gif`.

**About `gradients` in Opera Mini:**

Opera Mini use servers based on `Presto` browser engine to render the page. `Presto` version `2.10` can render `CSS3` gradients. Now Opera Mini 7.5 on Android (last version) use Presto `2.8` and Opera Mini 8 for `Blackberry` and `Java-browsers` use `2.9` version. So `2.10` is not so far (perhaps one year).

Also you can use css [inline `base64`](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) images via:

```
some_selecor { 
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,base64_image_code_here);
}
```

in `Opera Mini` and you can set your gradient as encode `background-image`.

**IMHO:**

`Opera Mini` use server farm render to save battery level on your phone and to save your traffic (size of request in `OBML` is only 10% of `HTTP` requests size of the same page). So render all CSS3 features it not the main target of this browser.